# Erro com query no Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estou tentando realizar a seguinte Query no hibernate:

```
    return this.entityManager
                .createQuery("SELECT u FROM UploadArquivoCondominio u WHERE "
                        + " u.condominio = :ucondominio ) "
                        + "AND u.dtinicio <= :hoje AND ("
                        + "u.dtfim IS NULL OR u.dtfim >= :hoje ) AND u.ativo = 1 AND")
                .setParameter("ucondominio", condominio).setParameter("dtinicio", hoje).getResultList();
```

e me apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ParameterTranslationsImpl.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterTranslationsImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.buildParameterMetadata(HQLQueryPlan.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1907)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
    at br.com.souvizinho.dao.UploadArquivoCondominioDAO.porCondominioDataInicioFim(UploadArquivoCondominioDAO.java:87)
    at br.com.souvizinho.controlador.UploadArquivoCondominioControlador.listar(UploadArquivoCondominioControlador.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1374)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Mas no SQL, ele trás os resultados esperados:

```
SELECT * FROM tbUploadArquivoCondominio AS u WHERE u.condominio = 1 AND u.dtinicio <= '2018-02-15 17:36:07.937' AND (
u.dtfim is null OR u.dtfim >= '2018-02-15 17:36:07.937' ) AND u.ativo = 1
```

Resultado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pode estar acontecendo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sua *query*, você está chamando o parâmetro de `:hoje`. Porém, ao evocar o método `setParameter`, você usa o nome `dtinicio`. Mude isso:

```
.setParameter("dtinicio", hoje)
```

Para isso:

```
.setParameter("hoje", hoje)
```

Além disso, parece haver um `AND` a mais no fim da sua consulta:

```
+ "u.dtfim IS NULL OR u.dtfim >= :hoje ) AND u.ativo = 1 AND")
```

E, também, um fecha parêntese sem que haja um abra parêntense:

```
+ " u.condominio = :ucondominio ) "
```

Comment: Outro detalhe, se puder acrescentar na resposta para ficar fixo, é que contém um ), sem abertura, na segunda linha. Aquela coisa de fim do dia e cansaço faz não vermos erros obvios de falta de atenção :)

Comment: @FelipeJunges Adicionado!